# VB Text Box accepting Non numeric Data

Tags: vb.net, textbox, numeric

I have a text box in VB which is set up to only accept only numeric data, and it works, except in TWO specific cases.

If the user provides a NON NUMERIC CHAR the text box self clears,

However, if the user first provides a number, then provides either '-' or '+'

The text box will accept this as a valid input.

When the user types one more char of ANY TYPE, i.e. number or char

Then the text box 'realises' and will self clear.

I was wondering if this is due to the way VB stores the chars '-' and '+'?

Is the best way around this to just add in the two exceptions, i.e. if '-' or '+' are input then self clear?

Or is there a more elegant solution?

Thank you.

Code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

'Textval used as variable from user input
'Numval becomes textval providing the user input is numerical

Dim textval As String
Dim numval As String

  textval = TextBox1.Text
  If IsNumeric(textval) Then
    numval = textval
  Else
    TextBox1.Text = CStr(numval)
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423114/checking-to-see-if-text-box-input-is-numeric?rq=1) might be worth reading as it may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Using a masked text box could be an alternative solution to what has been suggestted.

Answer (score 0):

code vb.net :

```
If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 13 AndAlso Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 AndAlso Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then
' your code here 
   e.Handled = True
```

End If

and you can Replace text :
code :

```
Text = Text.Replace("string", "replace_by_this_string")
```

Comment: And just where is he getting the `e` argument from in your code you provided? On another note your example of replace is irrelevant in whole, has nothing to do with his question.

Answer (score 0):

If the program requires the user to type only numeric data to the textbox, you should enforce the restriction when the user pressed a key

Use the textbox's `KeyDown` event:

```
'Omitting the parameters and Handles keyword
Private Sub textbox_KeyDown()
    'Set the keys you would want to allow in this array
    Dim allowedkeys As Keys() = {Keys.D1, Keys.D2, Keys.D3, Keys.D4, Keys.D5, Keys.D6, Keys.D7, Keys.D8, Keys.D9, Keys.D0, Keys.Back}

    For i = 0 To allowedkeys.Length - 1 'Iterate through the allowed keys array
        If e.KeyCode = allowedkeys(i) Then 'If the key pressed is present in the array...
            Exit Sub 'The check returned a success. Exit and accept the key
        End If
    Next
    e.SuppressKeyPress = True 'Supress all keys that failed the check
End Sub
```

Don't forget to add more keys that you need! The Space key, the numpad keys, the dot (point) keys?

This way you can remove the check in the `Changed` event and go directly to `numval = textval`

Or for those lazy programmers, `numval = TextBox1.Text` and `numval = Val(TextBox1.Text)` worked as well